# Customized Table CSS for a Single Table

Tags: html, css

I wanted to know if there a way to customer a single table without effecting all other tables on the page or site. I found this CSS which I like a lot but its calling the table tag along with other table elements and it effects all my tables on my site. I just want to be able to effect one table only. Here is the css:

```
table {
background: #f5f5f5;
border-collapse: separate;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 30px auto;
text-align: left;
width: 800px;
}   

th {
background: url(http://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png), linear-gradient(#777, #444);
border-left: 1px solid #555;
border-right: 1px solid #777;
border-top: 1px solid #555;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #999;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px 15px;
position: relative;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;  
}

th:after {
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,.08));
content: '';
display: block;
height: 25%;
left: 0;
margin: 1px 0 0 0;
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
width: 100%;
}

th:first-child {
border-left: 1px solid #777;    
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 #999;
}

th:last-child {
box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0 #999;
}

td {
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
padding: 10px 15px;
position: relative;
transition: all 300ms;
}

td:first-child {
box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 #fff;
}   

td:last-child {
border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 #fff;
}   

tr {
background: url(http://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png);  
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
background: #f1f1f1 url(http://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png);  
}

tr:last-of-type td {
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #fff; 
}

tr:last-of-type td:first-child {
box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0 #fff;
}   

tr:last-of-type td:last-child {
box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 #fff;
}   

tbody:hover td {
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
}

tbody:hover tr:hover td {
color: #444;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

Here is my html table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="48%" height="22" valign="middle">Course Description / Registration</td>
<td width="12%" height="22" valign="middle">Start Date</td>
<td width="7%" height="22" valign="middle"> Days</td>
<td width="20%" height="22" valign="middle">Location</td>
<td width="13%" height="22" valign="middle">Tuition</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" valign="middle"><a href="20150729GNJ.asp">21st Century Policing: Proactive Solutions</a></td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">07/29/15</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">01</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">Glassboro, NJ</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">No Cost</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" valign="middle">21st Century Policing: Proactive Solutions</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">07/30/15</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">01</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">Camden, NJ</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">No Cost</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" valign="middle">21st Century Policing: Proactive Solutions</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">08/20/15</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">01</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">Newark, DE</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">No Cost</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" valign="middle">Blue Courage: The Heart &amp; Mind of the Guardian</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">08/24/15</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">02</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">New Brunswick, NJ</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">$129 / $159</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
<td height="30" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to convert this to some kind of custom class like class="ThisTableDesign". If that's not possible I was thinking my next step would be to change things from table in ss to something for example:

```
/* This was called Table now I changed it to ThisTableDesign
ThisTableDesign{
background: #f5f5f5;
border-collapse: separate;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 30px auto;
text-align: left;
width: 800px;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, give it a class, and then change the css, targeting `.ThisTableDesign` on every selector

Comment: Can't you give the table a class or ID and use CSS rules bases on that?

Comment: Although this is a very simple question, I would like to thank you for following the guidelines of how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Is there a broad way to call it meaning for example if I want to use this only on special table can't I wrap it somehow for ex: .Mytabledesign { all table css above here } then call it in table tag ex: <table class="Mytabledesign" and have it effect this entire table? Is that possible?

Comment: @FrankG. Thats exactly how CSS selectors work. Check the answers below, and read the link provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu can definitely set up a class to target that table. Just make sure to change ALL the css to look for your class instead of all tables:

```
table {
```

becomes

```
.myTableClass {
```

Then preface the other selectors with your new class:

```
th {
```

becomes

```
.myTableClass th {
```

etc.

Comment: Going to try this now!! Will let you know how I made out thanks!

Comment: That did it thank you!! I see so because I put .MyTableClass in front off each of the css markup it then makes it joins all the code to .MyTableClass. Awesome thank you very much!!!

Comment: When you add .myTableClass before the th, tr, etc. you are telling the browser that it should only apply the associated styles to elements that are inside of an element with a class of .myTableClass AND are themselves elements of type th, tr, etc.  This increased specificity in the CSS allows you to target specific parts of your HTML without assigning a new class to every single contained element.  Much cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

Give the table an id in the HTML

```
<table id="mytablename">
    <!--table stuff here-->
</table>
```

And then in your CSS, reference it by id

```
#mytablename {
    /*lots of css rules*/
}
```

The rules you define in the css will ONLY apply to that one id. And you won't have to worry about it applying to any other table, as id's cannot be used multiple times like classes can.

(The answer above works very similar to setting a class, with slightly different syntax)

For more information, I would recommend reading [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Also add info to use descendent selector to target the th, td rules etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a base for all  on the site, you can declare in your css something like this :

```
.table {
  // CSS code
}
.table[class-ext="foo"] {
   // more CSS rules
}
```

and then add in your table element class-ext='foo'. Then, your table will be like :

```
<table class="table" class-ext="foo">
   ...
</table>
```